# Can you show compiler warnings for error:nil?

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, compiler-warnings

Is there a compiler setting that can warn about these? Currently I'm reviewing code and putting in `#warning don't use error:nil` whenever I see them.

(I know it's sometimes appropriate to do, but maybe there is a better way to have the compiler check sloppy error handling?)

Comment: I don’t believe there is, but consider filing a feature request with Apple asking for a compiler warning flag that would catch literal null pointers in error output parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since error:nil is completely legal and totally legit (as you even say), there is no way for the compiler to check it.

Comment: This is a bit of an overstatement. It is _possible_ for a compiler to issue a warning for legitimate statements; `if(x = 0)` is legal but generates a warning, for example.

Comment: Exactly, I was hoping for a warning like that for `error:nil`. I would gladly give up the 5% of the time when it is appropriate (by adding a superfluous &error) and have it warn me (and others) about unhandled errors.

Comment: @Josh Caswell - my answer was directly in response to the poster's question, not meant to be read that the compiler is incapable of issuing warnings for legitimate statements. Also, the warning you describe was added to clang as an ambiguity warning, which is not the case at all in this question.

Comment: @zekel - You'd be better off adding rules to the static analyzer to catch cases like this than trying to mess with the compiler. Realistically, though, the best way to catch stuff like this is through code reviews.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like that's the best answer there is.